# Where are the helm repos added on my windows computer

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Mine is a Windows 10 computer.

I ran the following command to [install official kubernetes helm](https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/) charts repository.

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

The installation was successful as it says.

I wanted to understand where they are installed.

Searched on my home folder, and also ProgramData but could not find.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Watching some videos, just found the answer.

Run the following command.

```
helm env
```

And you should see all the relevant locations.

And note, this works on ubuntu as well!

[image: Helm Location on windows machine]

Answer (score 1):

[These docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/) describe the helm default file location per operating system.
According to them, your repository files should be under `%TEMP%\helm`.